# symfony 4.4 get session id and delete a record in mariadb based on the matching session id

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

The session id is the primary key in the "session" table and another table "temp_sessions"
Upon logout the logout.php file is invoked and the below section gets executed.
How to write a SQL query to match the primary key (in this case session id) and then delete it from the other SQL table?

```
         */
    public function logout(MyUser $user)
    {
        $url = $this->getServiceUrl(__FUNCTION__);

        try {
            $this->logger->debug("SERVICE CALLED | Url: $url");
            $response = $this->getClient()->post($url, [
                'json' => [
                    'session_id' => $user->getSessionId(),
                ]
            ]);

            $real_session_id = $request->getSession()->get('_session_id');
            $sess_id = $request->getSession()->getId();
 
            // get the session id here and delete a record in the mariadb***

        } catch (\Throwable $exception) {
            $this->logger->critical("SERVICE EXCEPTION | Url: $url | Exception: " . $exception->getMessage());
            throw new ServiceException($exception->getMessage());
        }

        $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        $content = json_decode($content, true);

        if ('failure' === $content['result']) {
            $this->logger->error("SERVICE FAILURE | Url: $url | Message: {$content['message']}");
            throw new ServiceException($content['message']);
        }

        return $content;
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need SQL query? Don't you use Doctrine ORM along with Symfony?

Comment: Yes, I believe I need doctrine to write a query to delete. You are right, I do not need to write raw SQL queries.
Can you please suggest?

Comment: Read [this](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/working-with-objects.html#removing-entities)